# Move files to folders

Tags: vba

I have files and folders with same name how i can move this files to folder has same name.

Comment: First I doubt that you have files and folders with the same name, the file system won't accept that. Maybe the files have extensions? Be precise when you ask! Second, is this a programming question? If yes, please read [ask], then [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run it? What did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? If this is not about programming, the question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can move files between folders with `Scripting.FileSystemObject`. 
 
To do that, you can somenthing like in this `Sub`:

```
Sub MoveFiles()
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim SourceFileName As String, DestFileName As String

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
    SourceFileName = "C:\Users\myUser\Documents\Test.xlsx"
    DestFileName = "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\Test.xlsx"

    FSO.MoveFile Source:=SourceFileName, Destination:=DestFileName
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can use CMD to do that